# Read File in C#

Tags: c#

I found a C# source code that read from file which have 1000000 double number. The source code is below.

```
public void filereader()
{           
    using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\Hanieh\\Desktop\\nums.txt", FileMode.Open)))
    {
        int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length;
        byte[] fileBytes = b.ReadBytes(length);

        for (int ii = 0; ii < fileBytes.Length - 32 ; ii++)
        {
            savg1[ii / 2] = (double)(BitConverter.ToInt16(fileBytes, ii) / 20000.0);// inja error index midee
            ii++;
        }
    }
}
```

when I run source code to read from text file I have an error that related to savg1 index that is out of bound. I debug step by step and result shows size of length= 24000000 but savg1=1000000. my question is here: how this source code work and how I can fix this problem.

Comment: First tip: `File.ReadAllBytes` is a simpler way of reading all the bytes in a file... Now, we can't reproduce this as you haven't shown how you've declared or initialized `savg1`... it's not clear what you mean by "size of length= 24000000 but savg1=1000000"... if you mean the length of the file is 24000000 but the size of `savg` is 1000000 then that explains the exception... you need to initialize it to the right size, which looks like it needs to be  `(fileBytes.Length) - 32 / 2`

Comment: `fileBytes.Length - 32`  why `-32`?

Comment: `BitConverter.ToInt16` and `double`    16bit & 64bit...  hu?

Comment: declaration of savg1 is :
double[] savg1 = new double[1000000];
when alg run: line  int length = (int)b.BaseStream.Length; the length value assigned to 24000000 i do not no why!

Comment: i do not know why -32!

Comment: Did you copy/paste it?

Comment: yes, I have an algorithm in c# and try to implement it on android. This is one of the algorithm parts.

Comment: So you are using a `.txt` file to store binary data? Are you sure they are not written as plain text in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like this (`File.ReadAllBytes` and `BitConverter.ToDouble`):

```
  byte[] source = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Hanieh\Desktop\nums.txt");
  double[] data = new double[source.Length / sizeof(double)]; 

  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; ++i)
    data[i] = BitConverter.ToDouble(source, i * sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like:

```
double[] data;

using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(File.Open("C:\\Users\\Hanieh\\Desktop\\nums.txt", FileMode.Open)))
{
    // create array/buffer for the doubles  (filelength / bytes per double)
    data = new double[b.BaseStream.Length / sizeof(double)];

    // read the data from the binarystream
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        data[i] = b.ReadDouble();
}

MessageBox.Show("doubles read: " + data.Length.ToString());
```

Although, your file *nums.txt* implies that it is a textfile. You might not read it as a binary file.